# How to store history with "Append Changes to Existing Text"?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have multiple WF lists with approval running on them and we need to save history who edited, who send it, who approved it and so on. How could I achieve that with Append Changes to Existing Text? I know that I have to turn on versioning which I did. Also I am using Sharepoint Designer 2010.

Comment: Have you enabled "Append Changes to Existing Text" on multiple lines of text column?

Comment: Yes I did. I might have figured it out how to do it via WF.